# `Error: Invalid params: invalid format.` when deploying Contract to testrpc

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, testrpc

Tried to deploy a contract to `testrpc` network, but it is giving an error `Error: Invalid params: invalid format.`. Contract bytecode and ABI json is taken from [frozeman's example](https://github.com/frozeman/simple-dapp-example/blob/master/app/client/lib/ethereum-contract.js).

**deployContract.js**

```
Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

contractCode = '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';
abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"givenNumber","type":"uint8"}],"name":"setNumber","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"givenNumber","type":"uint8"}],"name":"guessNumber","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"SetNumber","type":"event"}];

GuessNumber = web3.eth.contract(abi)
var contractInstance = GuessNumber.new({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 200000, data: contractCode});
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\Code\testdapp\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:61
        throw errors.InvalidResponse(result);
        ^

Error: Invalid params: invalid format.
```

**testrpc** started using

```
testrpc -u 0
```

I am using `web3@0.20.1` and `TestRPC` v4.1.3. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Try putting '0x' in front of the contractCode. Something like `> var contractInstance = GuessNumber.new({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 200000, data: '0x' + contractCode});
`.

Comment: @Ismael After adding `0x` in front, running `node deployContract.js` no longer get the error, but seems to run forever.... Also an empty file is created `.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-9412`

Comment: That is odd, testrpc should mine it instantly. Are you sure that are connecting to testrpc? If you are deploying to a private network make sure to start mining blocks.

Comment: @Ismael Thats odd, right after I restarted `testrpc` and ran the node script again, it finally works and the transaction shows up in `testrpc` outputs. Didnt work when I restarted `testrpc` yesterday.

Comment: @Ismael After deploying the contract to `testrpc`, I notice that although `testrpc` reports `Contract created: 0xd73b47d14b81df86eb1653e845446202fbf9bd5d`, when I follow up `var contractInstance = GuessNumber.new(...)` with `console.log(contractInstance)`, I see that the `address` property is `undefined`. Should this be the case?

Comment: `contractInstance.transactionHash` is correct though... Its just `contractInstance.address` is `undefined`.

Comment: With web3 v0.20 it is correct, `new` (and `sendTransaction`) will return immediately with the transaction hash. You have to query `getTransactionRecipt(hash)` until it returns non null, and then check for `contractAddress` in the result. In web3 v1.0 was modified to return a promise, so you can `await` for the result.

Comment: @Ismael Is there a good reason to stay with v0.2 instead of upgrading to v1.0?

Comment: I can't answer that, you have to try it for yourself and check if it works for you. I've tried it about a month ago, the design seems nice, but it was too beta for me. Will check again later when starting a new project.